# php how does scaling work with imagecopyresized

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

as the question asks, how does it work:

I have a fixed image that is 171w x 191h and I am trying to scale it up by 50% but the new image is being cut off and skewed.

**UPDATE**: *the image bottom is being cut off...it seems to be scaling up to the full width, but the bottom of the image is being cut off.  If I  lower the the value "286" down to "255" or lower, the bottom of the image returns but it isn't scaled correctly.*

```
imagecopyresampled($img,$sourceImage,664,700,0,0, 256,286,171,191);  // scale up 50% = wonky
```

The image is being placed in $img properly and I am expecting to see the $sourceImage scaled up 50% (ie: 1.5 original size: 256x286) - but its just not coming out that way.

Parameters: This function accepts ten parameters:

```
$dst_image: It specifies the destination image resource.
$src_image: It specifies the source image resource.
$dst_x: It specifies the x-coordinate of destination point.
$dst_y: It specifies the y-coordinate of destination point.
$src_x: It specifies the x-coordinate of source point.
$src_y: It specifies the y-coordinate of source point.
$dst_w: It specifies the destination width.
$dst_h: It specifies the destination height.
$src_w: It specifies the source width.
$src_h: It specifies the source height.
```

Is there something special to understand about $dst_w/h and $src_w/h?  I am approaching this as $src_w/h are the current dimensions of the imported image and $dst_w/h are what I am trying to scale to?

Do note though, when I scale down it seems to work fine (on another image), orig size 1200x300:

```
imagecopyresampled($img,$banner,342,425,0,0, 900,225,1200,300);    // scale down 25% = works
```

Comment: What do you mean by "its just not coming out that way"? Is it failing to create an image? Creating one with the wrong dimensions? Scaling it in a way you didn't expect? Perhaps you can [edit] in some example images to show input, expected output, and actual output?

Comment: Besides scaling, you are also translating the image by placing it at 664,700. Can you try placing it at 0,0 instead?

Comment: i updated the OP....the bottom of the new image is being cut off..  It looks like its using the $dst_w instead of the $dst_h...because if I set $dst_h to the same as $dst_w then the full image appears

Comment: @ChrisHaas - its placement in the new image is correct.  I am taking 4 images and merging them into 1, basically in a sequential order: 1 = top, then 2, 3 and 4 = bottom.  So its placing correctly...

Comment: I figured it out....image 4 was being overlayed over the bottom portion of image 3, making it look like image 3 was being cutoff.  I need to rethink image 4.  Grrrr....was chasing the wrong gremlin all this time!